# How to override FEED_URI based on cli kwargs in a parent class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'd like to set the following in my parent crawlerclass since this should be the same for every child, how do I do that?

```
scrapy crawl spiderX -a full  >> FEED_URI = /xx/spiderX_full
scrapy crawl spiderX -a quick >> FEED_URI = /xx/spiderX_quick
```

this is what i have so far:

```
@classmethod
def update_settings(cls, settings):
    settings_dict = cls.custom_settings or {}
    feed_uri = path.join(settings.get('FEED_DIR'), '%s' % cls.name)
    settings_dict['FEED_URI'] = feed_uri
    settings.setdict(settings_dict, priority='spider')
```

how do i access the quick/full args from this function?
i tried doing it like this:

```
def __new__(cls, full=False, quick=False, *a, **kw):
    cls.full = full
    cls.quick = quick
    return super(MyCrawlSpider, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
```

but apparently update_settings runs before it

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-s` argument.

`scrapy crawl spiderX -s FEED_URI=s3://mybucket/path/to/export.csv`